msgraph-sdk-java : How to retrieve the Team ID and the Operations ID when creating a new Team?
I am using the msgraph-sdk-java 6 to try to create a room.
It seems pretty simple, you can find exemples on the Microsoft website. It work like this :
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

Team team = new Team();
team.setDisplayName("My Sample Team");
team.setDescription("My Sample Team’s Description");
HashMap<String, Object> additionalData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
additionalData.put("template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')");
team.setAdditionalData(additionalData);
Team result = graphClient.teams().post(team);

The issue is that because this triggers an asynchronous API, the returned object is always null, so I cannot retrieve information about the created team.
It seems that if you call the MsGraph API trough HTTP, this information is returned in the Response HTTP headers (more information here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60429979/7272010 ) but with the msgraph-sdk-java 6 the returned object is a Team object, and I cannot get the Response header from it.
Does anyone knows how to do this with the Java SDK 6 ?

Hello,
I don't know if this is a bug or if I am supposed to do differently.
Please can anyone help me ?
Regards
